# how to map properties of two object arrays with different lengths in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Being a newbie I have found this problem that I don't know to solve.

Given 2 arrays of different lengths I want to map the value of key total of `arr2` over the value of key total of `arr1` function of value of key `grpId` of `arr1`, as follow:

```
 arr1 = [{id: 1, grpId: 'x', total: null},
        {id: 2, grpId: 'x', total: null},
        {id: 3, grpId: 'x', total: null},
        {id: 4, grpId: 'y', total: null},
        {id: 5, grpId: 'y', total: null}];

 arr2 = [{id: 1, grpId: 'x', total: 3},
        {id: 2, grpId: 'y', total: 2}];
```

I need the result as below:

```
 arr1 = [{id: 1, grpId: 'x', total: 3},
        {id: 2, grpId: 'x', total: 3},
        {id: 3, grpId: 'x', total: 3},
        {id: 4, grpId: 'y', total: 2},
        {id: 5, grpId: 'y', total: 2}];
```

Comment: Create an object from `arr2` that maps `grpId` to the corresponding `total`. Then iterate over `arr1` and copy the totals from that object.

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are a number of questions about this kind of operation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
 const arr1 = [{id: 1, grpId: 'x', total: null},
        {id: 2, grpId: 'x', total: null},
        {id: 3, grpId: 'x', total: null},
        {id: 4, grpId: 'y', total: null},
        {id: 5, grpId: 'y', total: null}];

 const arr2 = [{id: 1, grpId: 'x', total: 3},
        {id: 2, grpId: 'y', total: 2}];

const output = arr1.map(entry => ({
    ...entry,
    total: arr2.find(a2 => a2.grpId === entry.grpId).total
}));

console.log(output);
```

Should see the output in your console window. (Developer tools of your browser).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.map()` to loop through `arr1`, and inside that loop through `arr2` and assign the `total` values:

```js
let arr1=[{id:1,grpId:"x",total:null},{id:2,grpId:"x",total:null},{id:3,grpId:"x",total:null},{id:4,grpId:"y",total:null},{id:5,grpId:"y",total:null}],arr2=[{id:1,grpId:"x",total:3},{id:2,grpId:"y",total:2}];
        
        
let res = arr1.map(el1 => {
    arr2.forEach(el2 => {
        if(el2.grpId == el1.grpId){
            el1.total = el2.total
        }
    })
    return el1
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Best to not directly assign to `el1`, but rather return a new object with the values you want. Otherwise it goes against the idea of pure functions without side effects in functional programming (as `map` is modeled after)